# add new op to tensorflow on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, google-colaboratory, embedding

I'm trying to compile some .cc  files on google colab (as shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/embedding) & [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op#define_the_ops_interface)) but I cannot find op.h file to include
I get the following error while compiling :

```
word2vec_ops.cc:16:10: fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/op.h: No such file or directory
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
word2vec_kernels.cc:16:10: fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/op.h: No such file or directory
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: header files are in "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/include/" but they're referenced to each other so many times!
changing all of them will not help

Answer (score 0):

You can compile .cc files on google colab with following gcc command:

```
$ gcc -Wl,-R/path/to/lib -I/path/to/include -L/path/to/lib -o myAppName mycode.c -llibapp2
```

find your library include path by

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.sysconfig.get_include()
```

Example:

````
!g++ -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/include -shared word2vec_ops.cc word2vec_kernels.cc -o word2vec_ops.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2```
````